# How to use OrganizationServiceProxy on my Plugin - CRM 2011?

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm-2011, fetchxml

I need to use fetch xml in a CRM plugin, and I found here an example on how to do that:

```xml
string groupby1 = @" 
    <fetch distinct='false' mapping='logical' aggregate='true'> 
     <entity name='opportunity'>
      <attribute name='name' alias='opportunity_count' aggregate='countcolumn' />  
      <attribute name='ownerid' alias='ownerid' groupby='true' />
      <attribute name='createdon' alias='createdon' /> 
      <attribute name='customerid' alias='customerid' /> 
     </entity> 
    </fetch>";

    EntityCollection groupby1_result = orgProxy.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(groupby1));
```

but there's something else I don't know how to use, or where is it to use.. it's the part which says:

```
orgProxy.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(groupby1));
```

I Know it's an object of the *OrganizationServiceProxy*, but where is it in the plugin class? I couldn't find out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the politest way possible, you probably need to take a few steps backwards to go forwards.

So to write a plugin, you need to implement `IPlugin`, which has just the one method

```
public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
```

The `IServiceProvider` is your window into CRM and the context of the event that you are hooking into.

Typically, you would do something like:

```
var context = (IPluginExecutionContext) serviceProvider.GetService(typeof (IPluginExecutionContext));
var factory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory) serviceProvider.GetService(typeof (IOrganizationServiceFactory));
var service = factory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);
```

In the example above, `service` is of type `IOrganizationService`. This gives you all the methods you would expect

```
service.Execute(foo);
service.RetrieveMultiple(bar);
service.Update(... /* etc
```

Might be worth reviewing some of the guides around this - as I've given in a previous answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11507590/tutorial-for-plugin-in-dynamic-crm-2011)

Comment: glosrob has the correct answer. I have a post on class I use to avoid having to repeat the "plumbing" for each Plugin. See: http://www.procentrix.com/Community/NickN/archive/2012/08/10/crm-2011-abstracting-plugin-setup.aspx

Comment: +1 for the politest way possible to tell somebody he's just waaay off. :)